# My VSTS 2008 has no Analyze menu. Where did it go?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, profiler

I have VSTS 2008 but no Analyze menu. Why did it happen in first place? And how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "VSTS 2008", do you mean **Visual Studio Team System ** or **Visual Studio Team Suite**. According to this an answer posted on this blog on MSDN [link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2007/09/22/new-for-visual-studio-2008-the-analyze-menu.aspxhttp://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2007/09/22/new-for-visual-studio-2008-the-analyze-menu.aspx) It's available in only Visual Studio Team Suite and Visual Studio Team Developer. Please post your Help About.

Comment: Oops! I somehow missed that there are 2 different kinds of VS. Team System and Team Suite...... Yes I have Team System installed....